# Saving Google Maps marker into Firebase db to be deleted later

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

Im working on a web app that uses Google Maps Api. Here is my problem
Im trying to save some Google Markers into Firebase DB to retrieve them at a different point in my web
applicaton, however Gooogle Firebase is throwing an errror when I try to save them.

```
var main_pts                            = {}; 
var location1                           = {}; 
location1.latitude                      = 'Random lat'; 
location1.longitude                     = 'Random long'; 

var location2                           = {}; 
location2.latitude                      =  'Random lat'; 
location2.longitude                     = 'Random long'; 

main_pts.location1                      = location1; 
main_pts.location2                      = location2; 

function create_main_vendor_pts(map){
    var main_Google_Markers = []; 
    var marker1             = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: main_pts.location1.latitude, 
            lng: main_pts.location1.longitude }, 
        icon: {
            labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 64),
            url: "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B3RD6FDNxXbdVXRhZHFnV2xaS1E"
        },
        label: {
            text        : 'Random', 
            color       : "yellow",
            fontWeight  : "bold",
            fontSize    : "20px"
        }
    }); 
    var marker2             = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: main_pts.location2.latitude, 
            lng: main_pts.location2.longitude }, 
        icon: {
            labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 64),
            url: "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B3RD6FDNxXbdVXRhZHFnV2xaS1E"
        },
        label: {
            text        : 'Random2', 
            color       : "yellow",
            fontWeight  : "bold",
            fontSize    : "20px"
        }
    });
    main_Google_Markers.push(marker1);
    main_Google_Markers.push(marker2);   
    add_Google_Markers_dB(main_Google_Markers);

}

function add_Google_Markers_dB(markers){
    var db_object                       = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i ++){
        db_object[`marker_${i}`] =  markers[i];
    }
    //console.log(db_object); 
    var db              = firebase.firestore();
    var db_reference    = db.collection('vendor_points_scheduled').doc('Main_Vendor_pts'); 
    db_reference.set(db_object).then(()=>{
        console.log("Data is in... "); 
    })
}
```

Please note that I want to save the Google Markers into Firebase for later retrieval and not their location.. etc. I was able to get the behavior that I wanted by saving
`main_Google_Markers` as a gloabal variable. However I want the the Google Markers since this chunk of code is called more than once making the global variable to be intialized

```
main_Google_Markers = []
```

[image: image of the error that is being thrown by Firebase DB]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of error messages.  Post them as text in your question (also useful to include them in the title).

Answer (score 0):

Firestore can only store the data types that are described in its documentation on [data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). You are trying to store `google.maps.Marker` objects, apparently contain data that cannot be mapped to these types.

Instead of trying to store the `google.maps.Marker` object itself, you should store the information that you need to create such an object. Then you can re-create the marker when you load the data back from Firestore.

Note that this question has been asked before, so I recommend reading some of the results you get when [searching for the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+Function+DocumentReference.set%28%29+is+called+with+invalid+data).